# What's happening in this Javascript code (line by line breakdown)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I'm still learning JS and was looking to build a grid/thumbnail carousel and found this piece of code. It's behaviour is really weird, as it displays 3 of the same image in a row (e.g. image 1 appears 3 times before image 2 is shown 3 times etc). I'm trying to understand what's happening in each line and was hoping someone could help me break down what's happening in each line?

Here is the code:

```
$('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item').each(function(){ 
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    for (var i=0;i<1;i++) {
        // next=next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

Here's what I think is happening in each line:

1. Creating a function that applies to every item in the carousel
2. declaring next as a variable (I read about using this yesterday but it's still not clear to me what it does -- just applies to every object that's changeable?)
3. check if next elements exist and if they do
4. then make next the siblings of the first selector?
5. declaring next children as anything that comes after the first child and add this to the variable/object this?
6. for loop where if the condition is met
7. not too sure what this line means
8. if next length exists
9. then next will equal objects siblings of first selector (why is this being repeated within the for loop when it was mentioned outside of it?)
10. not too sure why this is being repeated again too?

Any help would greatly be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes:

```
$('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item')
```

find all items with class `carousel` and data-type="multi", eg  
and then find all items with class `item` *within* .carousel

```
.each(function(){
```

loop over each of those items, `this` = each item

```
var next = $(this).next();
```

find the element that is directly after `.item` - no idea what this might be as you've not included the html

```
if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
}
```

if `this` was the last sibling, then get the first sibling, ie start again at the beginning

if carousel only had one item, then this would now be pointing back at `.item` (this) in the above loop.

```
next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
```

find the first child of next, copy it (clone) and add it as a child of the current `.item`

```
for (var i=0;i<1;i++) {
```

sets i = 0, but otherwise does nothing (loops i from 0 to 0), i isn't used, this does nothing

```
    // next=next.next();
```

move to the next item after the previous `next=`

```
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
```

same check as before, which makes no sense as next would have been set to the first sibling, so does nothing - this would make sense if you kept in `next=next.next();` to loop back to the beginning

```
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
```

repeats the previous clone

Which is why you get 3 images - there's (likely, no html evidence) only one `.item` and two lines of code to copy it to itself.